# SmsManager.sendDataMessage() gives Nullpointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sms

I'm writing a code for sending binary data to a specific port by using `sendDataMessage()`, but I can send only a small amount of data up to 120 bytes.

Sending large amount of data (130 bytes and above) causes a `Nullpointer` exception to be thrown.

Why is that and how do I send larger amounts of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to here:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3b8dc90cdc701f49/247db39ee62354c2?pli=1

Look at the 3rd response by "Justin(Google Employee)".

He states:

> Data messages sent over SMS are limited in length (133 bytes 
>   actually)

You're getting a problem at 130 bytes, which is obviously not the same as what he stated, but I bet it is just the fact that Data messages are limited. I believe this is because they require different encoding than regular sms messages so they can be directed at a specific port.

Comment: Thanx jaker, I already saw that link but what is the solution of this problem..?

Comment: Solution? Send a smaller message.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're hitting the maximum message size allowed.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Message_size and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS

The NullPointerException doesn't make much sense, but I guess that's just how it is.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3718